# Entity Framework Double relation between tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP .Net CORE MVC Website with Entity Framework and I have a double relation between two table :

**DocType**
#DocTypeName
#DocTypeValidationText

**TraductionInterface**
+id

DocTypeName and DocTypeValidationText are ForeignKey for the **TraductionInterface** table : One **DocType** have 2 **TraductionInterface**

here's my class :

**DocType.cs**

```
 public class DocType
{
    [Key]
    public int DocTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DocTypeName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DocTypeName")]
    public virtual TraductionInterface TraductionInterfaceName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DocTypeValidationText { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DocTypeValidationText")]
    public virtual TraductionInterface TraductionInterfacevalidationText { get; set; }
}
```

**TraductionInterface.cs**

```
public class TraductionInterface
    {
        [Key]
        public int TraductionInterfaceID;

        [ForeignKey("DocTypeName")]
        public virtual DocType DocTypeName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DocTypeValidationText")]
        public virtual DocType DocTypeValidationText { get; set; }

     }
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
builder.Entity<DocType>().ToTable("DocType").HasOne(d => d.TraductionInterfaceName).WithOne(t => t.DocTypeName);
            builder.Entity<DocType>().HasOne(d => d.TraductionInterfacevalidationText).WithOne(t => t.DocTypeValidationText);
```

but I got this error when I try to update

> Cannot call Property for the property 'DocTypeValidationText' on entity type 'TraductionInterface' because it is configured as a navigation property. Property can only be used to configure scalar properties.

**EDIT**
@user1672994's solution seem to have fix the problem but only the first relation is apply :
if
`builder.Entity<DocType>().ToTable("DocType").HasOne(d => d.TraductionInterfaceName).WithOne(t => t.DocTypeName);`
is before
`builder.Entity<DocType>().HasOne(d => d.TraductionInterfacevalidationText).WithOne(t => t.DocTypeValidationText);`
the `TraductionInterfaceName` relation is apply else it's the `TraductionInterfacevalidationText` relation. How can I make this 2 relation work together ?

Comment: If you do not want exposed foreign key ids, simply remove the `[ForeignKey]` attributes and EF will create them behind the scenes. Personally, I prefer to expose them.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself states that you should define the scalar property and while defining the `ForeignKey` relationship. The below code defines the relationship properties and use it while attaching the `ForeignKey` relationship

```
public class TraductionInterface
{
    [Key]
    public int TraductionInterfaceID {get; set; }

    public int DocTypeNameId {get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocTypeNameId")]
    public virtual DocType DocTypeName { get; set; }

    public int DocTypeValidationTextId {get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocTypeValidationTextId")]
    public virtual DocType DocTypeValidationText { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: Your solution seem to fix the error but now I 've an other error : The entity type 'TraductionInterface' requires a primary key to be defined. but TraductionInterfaceID as the annotations [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: Set the Key as `builder.Entity<TraductionInterface>().ToTable("DocType").HasKey(t => t.TraductionInterfaceID)`

Comment: I've try it, but got the error : `The properties expression 't => Convert(t.TraductionInterfaceID, Object)' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.` ps : it's to table("TraductionInterface") instead of ToTable("DocType") or i'm wrong ?

Comment: You are correct, it should be `table("TraductionInterface")`

Comment: Check if you have to define the `HasForeignKey` while defining the Entities

Comment: one to one or zero relations doesn't seem to work on the fluent API : `EntityTypeBuilder<DocType> doesn't contain definition for HasRequired` and HasForeignKey didn't work on one to one relation, I have these usings :  `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` if it help

Comment: For the Key Error, it was just the {get;set;} that was missing in the Key

Comment: Good! So your issue fixed?

Comment: No, see the edit above, I cannot have 2 relation, only the first is used, I made it work by editing manualy the migration file but it's not the good solution

Comment: Think you are looking for inverse property: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx